# Replace sensitive elements in a params hash to avoid mass assignment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters, mass-assignment

I would like to have a more systematic solution for myself to avoid mass assignment.

A typical situation is to remove id or user_id from params (submitted automatically via form) and replace it with current_user.id internally (in MyController#create).

A solution I can think of is to create object from params hash, then update_attributes (of parent and child objects) to replace sensitive attributes with internal values:

```
@user = User.create(:params[:user])
@user.update_attributes(:id => current_user.id)
@user.profile.update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
@user.preference.update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

Is there a shorter/more DRY way to say this?

If preference, profile etc. are child objects of user (created via build method), how can I write a method to look for their foreign keys for user and automatically replace them with the value I passed to parent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html)) are for. `attr_protected` will give you blacklist protection, while `attr_accessible` will protect using a whitelist.

While calling `update_attributes` right after a mass assignment would work, you're better off using the built in ways of protecting mass assignments as it won't require duplication of code every time you do a mass assignment on a model.

Comment: Thanks Zachary. Could you please elaborate on how you would do what I was trying to do with attr_accessible? I know about attr_protected etc., but I am not sure how to assign protected attributes in a DRY way.

Comment: It works the same way as `attr_protected`, but it's a whitelist instead of a blacklist. So if you have attributes named `name`, `email`, `password` you would do `attr_accessible :name, :email, :password` and then you can only mass assignment those 3 attributes.

Comment: Sorry, but my question is how do you actually handle these protected attributes in your controller.

Comment: @AdamNYC What I'm trying to say is, isn't the kind of thing you want to handle in the controller. Setting either of the attr_* methods I mentioned in the model classes will mean it's handled regardless of the controller you use it in.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a dumb question: Assume that I declare attr_accessible in my model, which does not include user_id. user_id can't be assigned from form. How will user_id is assigned to child objects of User then?

Comment: @AdamNYC You manually would define it. The code sample you gave wouldn't change, it would just mean you don't want to worry about the mass assignment anymore. I'm not really 100% clear on what you're saying the issue is.

Comment: Thanks Zachary. I got your point now. I don't worry about mass assignment with the solution I have in the code above. I just want to make it more DRY and more generic, so that I don't have to do it manually for every model.

Comment: @AdamNYC That's a bit different from what you originally asked.  If they are created through builder methods, eg `user.profile.new`, you shouldn't need to set user_id as long as `user_id` is set in the original `User` model.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in an earlier project by using:

```
@user = User.create(params[:user]) do |user|
    user.id = current_user.id
end
```

Would this work for you?

An alternative is to check out the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) and search for the `:as` for role based attributes.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. It would work, but it is still a bit ad-hoc to me. Furthermore, I would like to scan through all child objects to replace user_id with current_user.id.